# How to create a DataSet for RDLC reporting from a stored procedure "ObjectResult" using ADO.Net Entity Data Model

Tags: frameworks, ado.net, entity, rdlc

I'm trying to generate an `ObjectResult` as the `DataSource` for a `ReportViewer`. The report viewer is looking for a data table as the data source.

Is there an easy way to convert a stored procedure's `ObjectResult` for use as a RDLC data source?

The following is the current state of my code:

[image: Code with highlighted hurdles.]

Answer (score 0):

Created a utility to generate a DataSet from the generated list.